# Asynchronously call a method which accepts a string and returns an int in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Suppose you have a method as given below:

```
public int slowMethod(string ss)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("slow method exec starts");
        //Do some time taking work
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("slow method exec ends");
        return 1;
    }
```

And you have to call this method asynchronously but cannot change the signature of this method then how would you do it?

Comment: @MindSwipe actually in that question the `Foo` method was simple, it was not accepting or returning any value. I was facing this challenge so decided to post a new answer with a method which accepts and returns a value.

Comment: The core concept of the answer is "don't do it. Changing from sync to async will invariably bring API changes with it". Also, the method in the linked question does return a value, and it's trivial to add a parameter

Comment: @MindSwipe I was just playing around with async code in a Console application in C# and this question was asked to me in an interview so I thought to post an answer here.

Comment: If you need to run a synchronous method in another thread use `Task.Run(() => SlowMethod(""))`, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

create a wrapper class as shown below:

```cs
public async void slowMethodAsync()
{
    string ss = "my string value"; // or pass the value from caller of slowMethodAsync

    Task<int> T = Task.Run(() => {
        return slowMethod(ss);
    });

    var res = await Task.WhenAll(T);

    Console.WriteLine($"value of res[0]:{res[0]}");
}
```

And call `slowMethodAsync` from the `Main` method as shown below:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("main method begins");
    slowMethodAsync();                
    Console.WriteLine("main method end");
}
```

Console OUTPUT:

```
main method begins

slow method exec starts

main method end

//after 3 seconds

slow method exec ends

value of res[0]:1
```

It will be more benefecial when there are multiple `slowMethod` which needs to be run asynchronously.

Comment: You also can write `var res = await Task.Run ...` . Also, in the question, if you want to `Task.Delay(500)` to take effect, it must be awaited.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes we can but I have used `WhenAll()` so that we can call multiple slowMethods

Comment: Also, asynchronous method should return `Task` when possible.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Changed the code to use `Thread.Sleep()` instead. Thank you.

Comment: You will loose benefits of asynchronous execution then (thread just stops). I recommend using `await` operator on `Task.Delay`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I agree with you, actually I used. `Thread.Sleep()` to actually make `slowMethod`  a bit slow. Just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Please don't `async void` (unless you know it's only used as top level event handler). Small example of how that can unexpectedly break your entire application: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yRsATj